# iOS or macOS project: duplicate interface definition for ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to build a common Xcode project for macOS and iOS. My project directory structure is

```
MyApp
  Common
    AAPLAppDelegate.h
    AAPLAppDelegate.mm
    AAPLRenderer.h
    AAPLRenderer.mm
  MyApp_iOS
    AAPLViewController.h
    AAPLViewController.mm
    main.m
  MyApp_macOS
    AAPLViewController.h
    AAPLViewController.mm
    main.m
```

**build gives `Duplicate interface definition for class 'AAPLViewController'`.**

I have added `AAPLViewController.h` in *Build Phases -> Headers* of corresponding `macOS` and `iOS` schemes.

I have also assigned corresponding `macOS` and `iOS` target membership to all files in `MyApp_iOS` and `MyApp_macOS` folders.

I tried comparing my project to an working macOS and iOS project but couldn't find a clue to avoid the error.

[here](https://github.com/necktwi/MetalDeferredLighting.git) is the git repo of it; macOS code isn't complete yet but iOS target should be built without above error.

Comment: Did you check on which targets these files are included?

Comment: I don't know how to include a file in a target but I have assigned corresponding target membership for each file in the right side pane of Xcode. i.e. all files in `Common` folder have Both the targets checked, files in `MyApp_macOS` have `macOS` target checked and files in `MyApp_iOS` have `iOS` target checked in the `Target Membership` section on right side pane of the Xcode.

Comment: Yeah, check that you don't have any of these misassigned. If you don't find anything try cleaning your project, maybe some cached files are throwing the error.

Comment: yep, they are O.K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly setup your headers search paths. First, set `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` to `YES`. If that will not work - add only needed headers to `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` setting.

[image]

Comment: In your project I added `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS=YES` and faced with linker error about missing symbols so I can not provide full solution.

Comment: It worked though I have linker errors. I didn't modify any of the apple's sample code though I rearranged and copied files to build on macOS as well.

Comment: It seems its unable to find/create objects corresponding to logical sub folders like `Math`, `ModelLoader`. should the link directories should be modified? I am new to macOS.